# Nosuchmethodexception is throw in JSF application

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have multiple module using maven.
A, B,C,D. Project B,C,D depend org.apache.commons.common-lang3 (B: 3.4; C: 3.1, D:3.9).

> 

pom.xml (A project)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>link_to_B_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>link_to_C_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>link_to_D_project</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
...another dependency
```

pom.xml (B project)

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
...another dependency
```

In project B, I'm write escapeMethod using StringEscapeUtils.escapeJson and in project A, I call espaedMethod of B.
Nosuchmethodexception is throw.

I think common-lang3 of C project affected to A project but I can't explain

Everyone please explain for me.

Understand this issue

Comment: Seems like you are running issue with transitive dependency. One way to resolve the issue is to use the exclusions tag. Please have a look at https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions